# How to pass literal comma as argument

Tags: strings, arguments

I am using minted for code highlighting. I have defined a new minted file format, with the code

```
\newmintedfile[plaintextfile]{text}{
    ...
    breakafter=<values to break lines on>,
    ...
}
```

I'm only interested in the `breakafter` argument so I've filled the rest with ellipses - this is more of a latex question than a minted question.

If I want to break on a comma, how would I do that? Latex seems to ignore any comma value I use, such as

```
    breakafter=,,
```

or

```
    breakafter=\,,
```

How can I pass a literal character or string in latex? Thank you

Comment: What about `breakafter={,},`?

Comment: @Werner - it really was that simple! Create an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
breakafter={,},
```

to hide the `,` from the key-value list separation that also uses `,`.